# how to test LESS files are compiling?

Tags: css, meteor, less

In my Meteor app, I'm trying to include some LESS files but when I try to change a property in them it's not coming through on the browser... is there anyway to test to see if the LESS files are actually making it through/compiling?

Comment: Less files compile to css files, so if the css files don't change, the less is not working.

Comment: in Meteor... where can I see the LESS-compiled CSS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete working example of how to use less and see the compiled source.

```
> meteor create test
> cd test
> mkdir -p client/css
> touch client/css/site.less
> meteor add less
> meteor
```

Edit `client/css/site.less` with the following:

```
@color: #4D926F;

h1 {
  color: @color;
}
```

Navigate to `http://localhost:3000/`. Enjoy the colored `h1`.

If you are using chrome, open the developer tools, open the sources tab, select the `client/css/site.less.css?...` file. Enjoy the compiled source.